# Where do i start when applying finish to a table?

Tags: carpentry, polyurethane, table, spray-paint

So I'm spraying a bojo table with polyurethane. Sounds easy right!! Where should I start? Legs first so I don't have to lay the table on the topside if I where to do the top first? Does that make sense??
Thanks for your input and help guys

Comment: Hi there and welcome! This is a searchable Q&A site so it's generally most helpful to make sure your title is in the form of a question. That really helps others find things of interest to them (maybe they have the same question, or maybe they're an expert and can answer!) It would be best if you edited your question to have a more meaningful title. You're more likely to get help and also you're helping others

Comment: This would be a better question for the Woodworking stack.

Answer (score 2):

If you screw eye hooks in the bottom of the legs, you can suspend it and spray the whole thing.

If you can't suspend it, put the feet on painting pyramids and you can spray the whole thing.

If the above options don't work, do the feet and legs first and let it FULLY dry before flipping it to poly the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Polyurethane doesn't look very nice if you just do one coat. It's better to do multiple. If you do that you'll have to flip it anyway.

If you really want one coat and do flip, I'd say do it upside down first, then top last. First this will keep the coat of the top from being damaged while you do the bottom. Second, if the PU drips down sides it will look better if the drips are downwards not upwards. Of course wipe any droplets you can see before they dry.

If you don't want to flip at all, then just do it upright. You might not get much on the bottoms of the feet, which may or may not matter to you. You will also have less PU on the legs because it will flow down, and it may bulge at the bottom of the legs. It's easier to get an even PU coat if you can keep the surface horizontal while drying it. But the tabletop is the most important and at least that should get a pretty good coat this way.